# follower/following relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I understand how basic database relationships work but I am confused about the following/follower social media relationship in RDBMs.

Users table:

```
userId (PK)
email
name
```

Follow table:

```
followerId (FK referencing userId),
followeeId (FK referencing userId)
```

This seems to be the correct database design but what I really want to know if this is a one to many or a many to many relationship.

I think it is a many to many because a user can follow many users and be followed by many users. But it may be a one to many because each follow a user makes consists of one userId to follow. This isn't the perfect many to many example such as Students and Classes so it is confusing me. Thanks.

Comment: Can a follower follow many users? Can a user be followed by many followers? So, now you have your answer

Comment: I think it's a mistake to think about tables this way. Essentially, all relationships in a relational database are one-to-many. If they were one-to-one, you wouldn't need separate tables, and if they were many-to-many, you couldn't describe the relationship except through the use of junction tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your database design is consistent with your use case.

You have **many-to-many** relation between users, where a user may :

- follow many users
- AND be followed by many users

To represent this relationship, you have created a *bridge table*, the `follow` table. This is the relevant way to proceed.

The difference with a the typical Student/Class relation is that both objects being in relation are stored in the same table (`users`) : this is why you end up with two foreign keys in the `follow` table referencing `user.userId`. But regardless of this specifity, this is conceptually the same type of relationship.

Comment: Tips on an efficient many:many table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table